# What does JavaScript interpret `+ +i` as?

Tags: javascript

An interesting thing I've never seen before was posted in another question. They had something like:

```
var i = + +1;
```

They thought the extra `+` converted it to a string, but they were simply adding to a string which is what caused it to convert.

This, however, lead me to the question: what is going on here?

I would have actually expected that to be a compiler error, but JavaScript (at least in Chrome) is just fine with it... it just basically does nothing.

I created a little JSFiddle to demonstrate: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tpsstv1L/)

```js
var i = 5;
var j = + +i;
document.body.innerHTML = i === j ? 'Same' : 'Different';
```

Anyone know what's actually occurring and what JavaScript is doing with this process?

I thought maybe it would treat it like `++i`, but `i` doesn't increment, and you can even do it with a value (e.g., `+ +5`), which you can't do with `++` (e.g., `++5` is a reference error).

Spacing also doesn't affect it (e.g., `+ + 1` and `+ +1` are the same).

My best guess is it's essentially treating them as positive/negative signs and putting them together. It looks like `1 == - -1` and `-1 == + -1`, but that is just so weird.

Is this just a quirky behavior, or is it documented in a standard somewhere?

Comment: It looks to me like the `+` operator treats the left operand as optional.  If there is no left operand, it just returns the right operand.

Comment: the `+` or `-` operators with spaces between them are just simple `+/-` operators. you can do `+ + + 3` and it will give you `3`. Nothing weird about it

Comment: http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit

Comment: Only in Javascript could this question appear. Well, maybe PHP also.

Comment: I'm surprised by your surprise. It's the same in any language using infix notiation. C, C++, Java, C# VisualBasic, Pascal ... Unary minus gives the value with sign changed, unary plus gives the value with the same sign (so no op). The only quirk related to javascript is the automatic conversion from string to number

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Putting your the statement through the [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/Hby4m7ssuR), we can see that what we get here is two nested *Unary Expressions*, with the unary + operator.

It's a unary expression consisting of `+` and `+i`, and `+i` is itself a unary expression consisting of `+` and `i`.

The unary expression with the unary + operator, will convert the expression portion into a number. So you're essentially converting `i` to a number, then converting the result of that to a number, again (which is a no-op).

For the sake of completion, it works on as many levels as you add:

```
var i = 5;
console.log(+ + + + + +i); // 5
console.log(i); // still 5
```

Comment: Apparently you can chain these indefinitely: `+ + + + + + + + + 1` is valid JavaScript.

Comment: So this is the "buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo" of JavaScript.

Comment: I'm kind of shocked. I've been using JavaScript almost since there has been a JavaScript, and I've never come across the unary operators before. I've always used `parseInt` or its friends to convert to a number. Thanks.

Comment: @samanime "I've always used `parseInt`" as you should! Using `+i` to coerce is absolutely a hack and leads to the old "what happens if I do `++ + ++ +++ + ++i`?" questions you'll occasionally see in C++. Whitespace between operators is a Very Good Thing. :)

Comment: @samanime you've never used something like `var x = -y;` or `var a = -5;`?

Comment: @Mr.Mindor Of course, I have used that. It just never donned on my that it was a unary operator that could have done a conversion from string to number and had a positive counterpart. I always just kind of considered it a "negation" operator without putting a ton of thought into it.

Answer (score 9):

It's in the specification.

Digging through, we can see from [§14.6.2.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expression-rules) that the increment and decrement operators are listed before (and should be preferred) over the unary operators. So precedence alone won't explain this.

Looking up the [the punctuation table in §11.7](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-punctuators), we can see that every single instance of `++` (the operator) in the spec shows the two together, without whitespace. That's not conclusive, until you check...

[The whitespace rules in §11.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-white-space), specifically:

> White space code points may occur within a StringLiteral, a RegularExpressionLiteral, a Template, or a TemplateSubstitutionTail where they are considered significant code points forming part of a literal value. They may also occur within a Comment, but cannot appear within any other kind of token.

JS does not allow arbitrary whitespace mid-operator.

The JS syntax in both [PegJS](https://github.com/pegjs/pegjs/blob/master/examples/javascript.pegjs#L689) and [Esprima](https://github.com/jquery/esprima/blob/master/src/tokenizer.ts#L25) corroborate this, matching on the literal two-character string `++`.

Answer (score 6):

For me it's very clear;

```
var a = +3;
var b = +a; // same as a, could be -a, for instance
var c = + +a; // same as above, same as +(+a)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do `++variable` the javascript interpreter sees it as the [increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment).

If you do `+ +variable` the javascript interpreter sees it as [Unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), coercing the value to a number, twice.

So

```
var a = 1;
var b = +a;
var c = +b;

console.log(c);// still 1
```

is the same as

```
var c = + +1;
```

So the simple answer is that two plus signs can not be separated by a space to be interpreted as incrementation, the space makes it so the interpreter sees two seperate spaces, which is what it really is

Comment: Also equivalent to the more explicit `+(+1)`

Answer (score 2):

The + operators converts into a number, two + operators with a space in between does nothing additional.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it might look very similar, `+ +` and `++` are not at all the same thing for an AST interpreter. The same applies to token separation: `varfoo` is not the same as `var foo`.

In the expression `+ + +i`, each `+` is considered as distinct unary operator, which simply convert your variable to a number. For the incrementation operation, which is `++`, no spaces are allowed, neither between the + and the variable token. In the example below, the last line is not valid:

```js
var x = "4";
console.log(+ + +x);
console.log(+ + ++x);
console.log(+ ++ +x);
```